# Use of undefined constant SIGKILL - assumed 'SIGKILL' in Laravel 5.7 queue

Tags: mysql, linux, laravel, eloquent, queue

I'm getting this error "Use of undefined constant SIGKILL - assumed 'SIGKILL'" from my AJAX request, that starts this artisan command ->

```
        Artisan::call('queue:work', [
        'connection' => 'database',
        '--memory' => '700',
        '--tries' => '1',
        '--timeout' => '35000',
        '--queue' => 'updates'
    ]);
```

I'm using Laravel 5.7 as framework for application.

Jobs are managed from database, configuration ->

```
        'database' => [
           'driver' => 'database',
           'table' => 'jobs',
           'queue' => 'default',
           'retry_after' => 18000,
       ],
```

Problem appeared recently.. That is weird, because troubles wasn't here before and all this "system" worked just fine. Now worker get some jobs done just fine, but then it drops to error, and writes to table "failed_jobs" in DB this ->

```
ErrorException: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in /srv/migration-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458
```

As DB I'm using Microsoft Azure MySQL DB. Microsoft specialist after consultation find nothing .. server is working correctly. Queries are just fine, not that big to fail.

Please help, don't know what to do, or what is wrong...

Comment: Install PHP pcntl extension.

Comment: Thanks, troubles are resolved. :)